# Run Excel VBA code after 5 to 10 seconds randomly

Tags: excel, vba

I want to make an Excel VBA time delay that can run my script after 5 to 10 seconds randomly. Not a fixed time delay.

This has a fixed the time delay of 05 seconds.

```vb
Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
```

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use `WorksheetFunction.RandBetween`:

```
Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(5, 10))
```